# Java Label that can be closed

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel

I was wondering if I could create a JLabel that could be closed.
This is my code:

```
package Bank;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;

public class BankLogin {
  String usernameuser;
  String passworduser;
  ArrayList<String> Usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> Passwords = new ArrayList<String>();
  private JFrame frame;
  private JTextField Username;
  private JTextField textField_1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                BankLogin window = new BankLogin();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
  public BankLogin() {
    initialize();
  }

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
  private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 508, 381);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel Messages = new JLabel("New label");
    Messages.setBackground(Color.RED);
    Messages.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    Messages.setBounds(99, 132, 383, 75);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Messages);
    Messages.setVisible(false);

    Username = new JTextField();
    Username.setBounds(231, 66, 131, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Username);
    Username.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(231, 132, 131, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
    lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblUsername.setBounds(109, 66, 112, 36);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblPassword.setBounds(109, 125, 112, 36);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        }
    });

    btnLogin.setBounds(109, 240, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

    JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
    btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if((lblUsername.getText()).length() != 0 && (lblPassword.getText()).length() != 0){
             Usernames.add(lblUsername.getText());
             Passwords.add(lblPassword.getText());
             Messages.setVisible(true);
             Messages.setText("Thank you for creating an account.");
            // Messages.setVisible(false);
            }
            else{
                 Messages.setVisible(true);
                 Messages.setText("Error");
            }
        }
    });
    btnRegister.setBounds(273, 240, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnRegister);
  }
}
```

The program is basically a login/register thing. I made two arrays that store the Username and Password seperately. After the user registers, I made a Jlabel to say thank you for registering, but I want it able to be closed by the user.
Right now I need to set the visiblity of messages to false, but is there another way?

Comment: Another way like maybe a dialog box?  Check out [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), in particular [showMessageDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) and friends.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is another way.  Instead of using a label you can use a JButton which has been formatted to look just like a label.  Except, that when you click on it the text disappears.  You add an action listener to remove the text when the button is clicked.  Try the code below.  The new and changed code is marked with comments to that effect.

```
package banklogin;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;

public class BankLogin {
  String usernameuser;
  String passworduser;
  ArrayList<String> Usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> Passwords = new ArrayList<String>();
  private JFrame frame;
  private JTextField Username;
  private JTextField textField_1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                BankLogin window = new BankLogin();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
  public BankLogin() {
    initialize();
  }

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
  private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 508, 381);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton Messages = new JButton("New label");             // new
    Messages.setBorderPainted(false);                        // new
    Messages.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));          // new
    Messages.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));    // changed
    Messages.setBounds(50, 175, 383, 50);                    // changed
    frame.getContentPane().add(Messages);
    Messages.setVisible(false);

    Username = new JTextField();
    Username.setBounds(231, 66, 131, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Username);
    Username.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(231, 132, 131, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
    lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblUsername.setBounds(109, 66, 112, 36);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblPassword.setBounds(109, 125, 112, 36);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        }
    });

    Messages.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  // new
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {   // new
            Messages.setText("");                      // new
        }                                              // new
    });                                                // new

    btnLogin.setBounds(109, 240, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

    JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
    btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if((lblUsername.getText()).length() != 0 && (lblPassword.getText()).length() != 0){
             Usernames.add(lblUsername.getText());
             Passwords.add(lblPassword.getText());
             Messages.setVisible(true);
             Messages.setText("Thank you for creating an account.");
            // Messages.setVisible(false);
            }
            else{
                 Messages.setVisible(true);
                 Messages.setText("Error");
            }
        }
    });
    btnRegister.setBounds(273, 240, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnRegister);
  }
}
```